# How to check variable type is map in Go language

Tags: go

```
map1 := map[string]string{"name":"John","desc":"Golang"}
map2 := map[string]int{"apple":23,"tomato":13}
```

so,How to check variable type is map  in Go language？

Comment: Notice that Go has static typing. If you declare map1 and map2 as you do in your example code, they will always be a map.

Comment: It won't compile and tells you an error if you don't use with correct types. But moreover, you'd also want to define each structure like `type hackers map[string]hacker` and `type fruits map[string]fruit` so that you can add methods to each struct

Answer (score 20):

You can use the reflect.ValueOf() function to get the Value of those maps, and then get the Kind from the Value, which has a Map entry (`reflect.Map`).

http://play.golang.org/p/5AUKxECqNA

http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind

Here's a more specific example that does the comparison with reflect.Map:
http://play.golang.org/p/-qr2l_6TDq

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "reflect"
)

func main() {
   map1 := map[string]string{"name": "John", "desc": "Golang"}
   map2 := map[string]int{"apple": 23, "tomato": 13}
   slice1 := []int{1,2,3}
   fmt.Printf("%v is a map? %v\n", map1, reflect.ValueOf(map1).Kind() == reflect.Map)
   fmt.Printf("%v is a map? %v\n", map2, reflect.ValueOf(map2).Kind() == reflect.Map)
   fmt.Printf("%v is a map? %v\n", slice1, reflect.ValueOf(slice1).Kind() == reflect.Map)
}
```

prints:

```
map[name:John desc:Golang] is a map? true
map[apple:23 tomato:13] is a map? true
[1 2 3] is a map? false
```

If you want to know the more specific map type, you can use reflect.TypeOf():

http://play.golang.org/p/mhjAAdgrG4

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fmt` and avoid using reflection.

```
func isMap(x interface{}) bool {
    t := fmt.Sprintf("%T", x)
    return strings.HasPrefix(t, "map[")
}

map1 := map[string]string{"name": "John", "desc": "Golang"}
fmt.Printf("map1 is a map? %t", isMap(map1))
```

Produces:

```
map1 is a map? true
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OVm-_jgz33r

Reflection is discouraged in Go. To quote Rob Pike, 
"[Clear is better than clever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=14m35s)" and "[Reflection is never clear.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=15m22s)"

Comment: This works, but it is probably much slower than using reflection.